# Mocha Chai with Nock: why am I getting timeout errors when doing cleanup in 'after()' and 'afterEach()'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, nock

I'm stubbing (mocking?) a fetch request with Nock in a mocha/chai suite and it seems to work fine.  But when I want to clean up and set things back to normal after the `describe` I'm doing the nock stub in, I get mocha timeout errors.

My setup for nock (I'm going to do this before each `it`, with different URLs, right now I am only doing it for one) is

```
it('should succeed for correct nickname, move and gameID with game in progress', () =>
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(_ => {
          nock('http://localhost:8080')
            .post(`/api/user/${nickname}/game/${gameInProgress.id}`)
            .reply(200, {
              message: 'successful move'
            })
          return logic.makeAGameMove(nickname, nickname2, {from: "e2", to: "e4", promotion: "q"}, gameInProgress.id, token)
        })
      .then(res => {
        const {message} = res
        expect(message).to.equal('successful move')
      })
```

and at the end of the `describe` I have

```
 afterEach(_=> nock.cleanAll())
 after(_=> nock.restore())
```

But I keep getting the following errors

```
        "after each" hook for "should succeed for correct nickname, move and gameID with game in progress":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. 
  "after all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I'm at a bit of a loss.  I even tried to wrap the calls to `nock.cleanAll` and `nock.restore` in Promises, but it didn't help.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supplying an argument to your arrow functions. Mocha thinks you are using `done`, you just need to make it so no arguments are used.

```
(()=>nock.cleanAll())
```

Instead of:

```
(_=>nock.cleanAll())
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are testing an async function, chai needs to be informed that the function being tested is async. Here is a way you do it by prepending `async` keyword before your `async` functions;

```js
it('should succeed for correct nickname, move and gameID with game in progress', async () =>
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(_ => {
          nock('http://localhost:8080')
            .post(`/api/user/${nickname}/game/${gameInProgress.id}`)
            .reply(200, {
              message: 'successful move'
            })
          return logic.makeAGameMove(nickname, nickname2, {from: "e2", to: "e4", promotion: "q"}, gameInProgress.id, token)
        })
      .then(res => {
        const {message} = res
        expect(message).to.equal('successful move')
 });
```

and then prepend `async before the fcallback functions`

```js
 afterEach(async _=> nock.cleanAll())
 after(async _=> nock.restore())
```

Comment: Thanks -- I tried your solution but it didn't seem to work for me....as I said, I'd tried to wrap `after` and `afterEach`  in Promises but it also didn't work.  As an aside, why do `after` and `afterEach` need to be async?  Are `nock.restore` and `nock.cleanAll` async?